# How to create an excel file if the script stop executing

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

I am reading an excel file which contain multiple unique numbers, which i use to perform request activity on a REST API. At the end of the program, I am trying to write another excel file where i am writing the status as 'Success' or 'Fail'.

The issue is, I am reading a file which contain data over 100k numbers. So if my program stop at any reason, or even i stop it intentionally, the output excel file never create. How do i make sure to get the output file till my script run.

here is my code.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import requests
from datetime import datetime

def api_status():
    wk = Workbook()
    ws = wk.active

    start_row = 2
    start_column = 1
    status_column = 2

    wk = load_workbook("Data-File.xlsx")
    source = wk["Sheet"]

    global IDNO
    for id_list in source['A']:
        IDNO = id_list.value
        url = "someURL"
        payload = {'id_no': str(IDNO)}
        headers = {}
        response = requests.request("POST", json_url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
        json_obj = response.json()

        ws.cell(row=start_row, column=start_column).value = IDNO

        json_message = (json_obj.get('message'))
        if json_message == "Success":
            ws.cell(row=start_row, column=status_column).value = "Success"
            start_row += 1

        else:
            print("NO")
            ws.cell(row=start_row, column=status_column).value = "FAIL"
            start_row += 1

    wb.save("STATUS-FILE-%s.xlsx" % datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y_%I-%M-%S_%p"))

api_status()
```

Comment: I think @Ofer Sadan is on the right lines, but use finally rather than except so that your code runs regardless of exception.

Comment: @ZachCleary You are correct, I added a `finally` to make sure at least the `save` happens

Comment: There is no need to use `global` here. In fact, you'll probably never need this.

Comment: Thanks @CharlieClark. I will remove it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just fallback on some code by using a `try... except`. Replace this line:

```
api_status()
```

With this block of code:

```
try:
    api_status()
except:
    # CODE TO WRITE YOUR "FAIL" STATUS
```

Or we can do this for the loop inside the function. Of course there's a little more to it than that. You can specify specific actions to be taken for different error types, or you might want to put that `try...except` block inside of your function to control for specific lines failing and carrying out the rest.

I'm assuming the most likely error would come from your web request. In that case:

```
try:
    response = requests.request("POST", json_url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
    json_obj = response.json()
except:
    json.obj = {}
```

By making `json_obj` an empty dict if the request doesn't work, I guarantee that the next lines would write `FAIL` in your excel instead of `Success`

Combining both ideas to make sure your code reaches the `save` as well would look like this (using a `finally` to make sure it runs in any possible case):

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import requests
from datetime import datetime

def api_status():
        wk = Workbook()
        ws = wk.active

        start_row = 2
        start_column = 1
        status_column = 2

        wk = load_workbook("Data-File.xlsx")
        source = wk["Sheet"]
    try:
        global IDNO
        for id_list in source['A']:
            IDNO = id_list.value
            url = "someURL"
            payload = {'id_no': str(IDNO)}
            headers = {}
            try:
                response = requests.request("POST", json_url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
                json_obj = response.json()
            except:
                json.obj = {}

            ws.cell(row=start_row, column=start_column).value = IDNO

            json_message = (json_obj.get('message'))
            if json_message == "Success":
                ws.cell(row=start_row, column=status_column).value = "Success"
                start_row += 1

            else:
                print("NO")
                ws.cell(row=start_row, column=status_column).value = "FAIL"
                start_row += 1
    finally:
        wb.save("STATUS-FILE-%s.xlsx" % datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y_%I-%M-%S_%p"))

api_status()
```

Comment: Hi @Ofer Sadan. Thank you for your answer. I tried your solution but it is not still saving the output file whenever i stop the program forcefully. I tried both method using try and finally and also "try: api_status() except:". none of these is saving my output file

Comment: @AliKhan stopping forcefully just kills the process, so nothing can happen at that point. Perhaps move the `save` inside the loop, but overwrite the same file over and over again. It will make your program much slower, but it will always save the last result

Comment: Thanks @Ofer Sadan.